# Session token right usage with API

Tags: android, api, session, mobile, token

Can anyone please explain -
I am writing a Php code that will allow a mobile app (Android) to get data from the DB.

I read about using a token but where do I save this token on the server side?

(I tried it, but the session token variable doesn't exist I assign it - for example, if I call it the second time.)

```
<?php

session_start();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM a_users WHERE a_mail = '".$_POST["mail"]."' AND a_pw = '".$_POST["pw"]."'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    $value = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $Token_API = encryptMyVar(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    $_SESSION["Token_API"] = $API_Token;
    $value = array("login" => 1,"token_api" => $Token_API,"nickname" => $value["nickname"]); 

    $con->close();

    exit(json_encode($value));
}
?>
```

should i save the token in a file on the server or something or am I doing something wrong?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Can you please post any code? We can help you fix your code, we don't want to give you the answer ;).

Comment: thank you, I added the php code. any idea how to use the token?

Answer (score 1):

So after looking at your code, it isn't a big problem. All you have is the variable your are setting the Session to is `$API_Token`, that variable doesn't exist. You should mean to set `$_SESSION["Token_API"]` to `$Token_API`. Your final code should look something like this:

```html
<?php

session_start();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM a_users WHERE a_mail = '".$_POST["mail"]."' AND a_pw = '".$_POST["pw"]."'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    $value = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $Token_API = encryptMyVar(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    $_SESSION["Token_API"] = $Token_API; //Replaced $API_Token with $Token_API
    $value = array("login" => 1,"token_api" => $Token_API,"nickname" => $value["nickname"]); 

    $con->close();

    exit(json_encode($value));
}
?>
```

Please do tell me if this solves your problem ;).

Comment: Hi, thank you.
You are right that I missed there with a variable, though this is just a copy-paste issue.

My big question is - how to use the token properly when using an API?

I have a mobile phone (android) that is calling my Php code.
The session is erelevant because it does not save any variables on the server.